# Multiple setInterval() using array

Tags: arrays, setinterval

I want to animate all three circles using this one script.
But to achieve this, I need to create 3 variables like 'c1' right?

I got the code to work by duplicating everything: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JwkYm/339/
It has to be easier then this. Thanks for your help in advance.

```js
(function () {
    // math trick 2*pi*57 = 358, must be less than 360 degree 
    var circleArr = ['orange-halo','orange-halo2','orange-halo3'];
    var myTimerArr = ['myTimer','myTimer2','myTimer3'];
    var interval = 30;
    var angle = [0,0,0];
    var angle_increment = 6;

    var c1 = setInterval(function () {
        
        var x = 0;
        
        while(x >= 2)
        {
         document.getElementById(circleArr[x]).setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", angle[x] + ", 20000");
          document.getElementById(myTimerArr[x]).innerHTML = parseInt(angle[x]/360*100) + '%';
          
          if (angle[x] >= 270) 
          {
            c1.clearInterval(c1.timer);
         }
          
         angle[x] += angle_increment;
          x++;
        }      
    }.bind(this), interval);
```

```css
#myTimer, #myTimer2, #myTimer3 {
  fill: #000099; 
  font-size: 40px; 
  font-family: Myriad light;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:300; height:300; top:0; left:0;">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="73" id="blue-halo" fill="none" stroke="#000099" stroke-width="30" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="73" id="orange-halo" fill="none" stroke="#FD6400" stroke-width="31" stroke-dasharray="0,20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    <text id="myTimer" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110">0%</text>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:300; height:300; top:0; left:0;">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="73" id="blue-halo2" fill="none" stroke="#000099" stroke-width="30" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="73" id="orange-halo2" fill="none" stroke="#FD6400" stroke-width="31" stroke-dasharray="0,20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    <text id="myTimer2" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110">0%</text>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:300; height:300; top:0; left:0;">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="73" id="blue-halo2" fill="none" stroke="#000099" stroke-width="30" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="73" id="orange-halo2" fill="none" stroke="#FD6400" stroke-width="31" stroke-dasharray="0,20000" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
    <text id="myTimer3" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="110">0%</text>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JwkYm/341/